# Does ConTeXt fail in the LMTX environment with the Lettrine module?

Tags: margins, context, lettrine, drop-cap

I have been successfully using ConTeXt MkIV for all my documents.

So far, everything has gone well with this TeX flavour in my Arch Linux distribution thanks to the *context-minimals* package installation from AUR.

A few days ago I installed the *luametatex* package, also from AUR.  Then, I switched from **ctx** to **lmtx** to compile my ConTeXt documents. This is the only thing that has changed in my workflow so far (my preambles are the same, and I haven't had to change anything within my `\input` files either).

Nothing has changed either in my pdfs, except for some odd behaviour of LMTX with Lettrine: my dropped capital letters are not integrated into the text, but stay inside the margin, as seen below.

[image]

However, every time I return to the ConTeXt MkIV environment (**ctx**) everything works perfectly again with the same `context preamble.tex` command:

[image]

Has anyone in this forum experienced the same strange behaviour between LMTX and Lettrine with ConTeXt in the *TeX Live* distribution or with *ConTeXt Standalone*?

My LuaMetaTex version is 2.07.10

I also add an extract from my code consisting of separate parts that I write here joined together one after the other, which the new LMTX might not like:

```
\setuplanguage[es][leftquotation=«,rightquotation=»]     
\mainlanguage[es]
\definepapersize[mybook][width=6in,height=9in]     
\setuppapersize[mybook]

\usemodule[lettrine]
\def \LettrineStyle     
  {\definefontsynonym[LettrineFont][Bold]\dropcapitals
\setuplettrine[A][Lines=3,Slope=4pt,Findent=-3pt,Hang=0.04,FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[L][Lines=3,Hang=0.06,Findent=-6pt,Nindent=12pt, FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[E][Lines=3,Hang=0.10,FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[B][Lines=3,Hang=0.04,Raise=0.00,Oversize=0.00, FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[R][Lines=3,Oversize=0.04,Hang=0.06,Raise=0.00, FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[Q][Lines=3,Hang=0.08, Nindent=1em,Raise=0.16,Oversize=-0.10, FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]
\setuplettrine[M][Lines=3,Hang=0.06,Raise=0.00,FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]     
\setuplettrine[W][Lines=3,Hang=0.04,Raise=0.00,Findent=2pt,Slope=-4pt, Nindent=-4pt,Oversize=0.00, FontHook={\LettrineStyle}]

\definefontfeature[body]     
[mode=node,calt=no,itlc=yes,
liga=yes,dlig=no,hlig=no,
rlig=no,tlig=yes,kern=yes,swsh=yes,     
onum=yes,salt=no,script=latn,pnum=yes,     
protrusion=quality,expansion=quality]     
\definefontfamily[mainfont][rm][cochineal][features=body]

\setuplayout % global  layout
[
grid=yes,
%backspace=52pt,
%width=318pt,     
width=fit,     
topspace=36pt,     
header=12pt,     
headerdistance=13.50pt,     
height=569pt,     
footer=26pt,     
footerdistance=12pt
]
\definegridsnapping[tolerant]

\definefontsize[t]     
\definefontsize[u]     
\definefontsize[v]     
\definefontsize[w]     
\definefontsize[y]     
\definefontsize[z]
\definebodyfontenvironment[12.46pt][t=12.00pt, 
u=11.30pt,v=15.20pt,w=8pt,y=30pt,z=10.20pt]      
    \switchtobodyfont[12.46pt]                  
    \setupbodyfont[mainfont]                  
    \setupindenting[yes,medium]                  
    \setupalign[hz,hanging,height]
    \setupinterlinespace[line=15.45pt]
```

Although my knowledge of how Lettrine works is almost useless, I suspect that something has to do with how this module handles paragraphs. Could this have changed with LMTX?

I've spent a few hours trying here and there. This is an example with a test epigraph. Although the result is correct, I'm confused: it's not compiled using MkIV, but with the same **lmtx** environment and command as the former main text.

[image: Compiled with LMTX]

Yes, it is compiled again with LMTX, without changing a single digit of my old code; only, of course, I have added the necessary code to create my sample epigraph. Now I will share below the code I have added to include it.

```
\usemodule[annotation]
\definelayout[epigraph]
    [
      backspace=176pt,
      width=194pt
    ]
    \defineannotation
      [Epigraph]
      [
        alternative=command,
        style=tfa,
        spacebefore=small,
        spaceafter=big,
        command=\PlaceEpigraph,
      ]
    \define[2]\PlaceEpigraph
      {\startalignment[hanging,flushleft,nothyphenated]
    \setupinterlinespace[line=22pt]
    \placeannotationcontent
    \stopalignment}

\startmakeup[standard][doublesided=yes]   
\setuplayout[epigraph]     
\startEpigraph      
\lettrine{A}{hora} \switchtobodyfont[initialtext],rest of my dummy text.      
\stopEpigraph     
\startalignment[flushright]          
    \blank[0.8cm,force]{\tfa\sc Geofrey Chaucer,\hspace[big\blank[0.1cm,force]
    {\switchtobodyfont[initialtext]\tfa\em The Canterbury Tales \hspace[big]}             
\stopalignment       
\stopmakeup
```

I find no explanation for this correct result, which distances itself from the anomaly that LXMT and Letrine give us as a rare output in the main text once again.

It is quite possible that this enigma has to do with the revealing [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg95232.html) that **mickep** has provided us with. But I have no advanced knowledge of the code to relate it to the content of that thread, as well as to clear up the doubts that its solution causes me, which for the moment seems not only the best, but the only one.

By the way, in connection with the warning from Hans Hagen within his [announcement](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg95232.html), and more specifically referring to `\forgetparagraphfreezing`, can anyone explain to me in plain language why it is relevant to keep the paragraphs frozen? Rather, and to be totally honest, I don't know what means

> ...in lmtx we everywhere expect freezing to be enabled.

Comment: @mickep Of course. Just keep in mind that if I haven't uploaded it, it's because the code hasn't changed at all.  It's a code that has worked for me for years without problems with MkIV, but as you say, it now works with a (non) in front when it comes to LMTX. I'll do it immediately when I get home.

Comment: Maybe it is because of [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg95232.html). Does it work as it used to if you add `\forgetparagraphfreezing`?

Comment: @mickep You hit the bull's-eye. But this possible solution poses a dilemma for me because of my poor knowledge of some fundamentals. I have reread the entire thread of your [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg95232.html) over and over again. It seems that this solution, apart from being temporary while Hans is checking the LMTX code, may cause some adverse effects.  I am concerned about the possible meaning of _it might have other side effects once in lmtx we everywhere expect freezing to be enabled_ on the Hans' advise. Why is it so important to freeze paragraphs?

Comment: On the other hand, I am playing with the code of a dummy epigraph, and I find something puzzling for me about this LMTX issue. I will illustrate this in my former question in a little while.

Comment: If I were you I would probably send this question to the mailing list instead (maybe mentioning that you tried here). I guess Hans is the best person to answer about the plans.

Comment: @mickep Your advice may be the most practical way at this time. I don't remember if I have an account on that mailing list. I don't know their rules of use and routines, but maybe it's worth giving it a try. Your contribution has been invaluable to me.